# Program hangs in Xcode debugger, but not in Instruments

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, debugging, lldb

I'm working on debugging a game written in C++ and it recently started hanging on the splash screen when I try to run it in Xcode (in Debug mode). I can't identify any changes in my code that could have caused this, and there aren't any log messages being printed while this hang is happening (something that I know can severely slow down a program). I then opened Instruments and used the time profiler to try and find the source of the problem, but when I ran my program on the time profiler it progressed past the part where it hangs, and ran as expected. Both running and profiling are set to use Debug mode so the build is the same, does anyone know what could possibly cause an issue like this?

More info: I'm using LLVM/Clang as the compiler and LLDB as the debugger. Looking at Activity Monitor during the hang I can see the game is shown as 'not responding' and Xcode is using a lot of CPU activity, despite not printing any log messages etc.. In 'Edit Schemes' the Profile scheme is set to use the Run action's arguments and environment variables.

Comment: Start the program in Xcode and wait until it hangs, then go to Activity Monitor, find your process, and hit `Sample Process` - that will then give you a stack trace showing you where you are hanging.

Comment: Wow! Didn't know about that feature. I've managed to find what I suspect is the function causing the problem, but I'm still not sure why it is consistently working when profiling but not when debugging. Is there anything different about the way programs are run when profiling/debugging that could help me isolate the problem?

Comment: In terms of threads that aren't waiting on my application code, I've found that two apparently unnamed threads appear to be spending 100% of their time on `mach_msg_trap` and `__psynch_cvwait`. Any idea what these could mean?

Comment: It sounds like you may have some sort of deadlock or race condition between two threads - it may be that this is timing-dependent, hence the different behaviour in Instruments. Thread-related bugs can be hard to track down, unfortunately.

Comment: It turns out disabling one of my breakpoints (a breakpoint with a condition that may not have been using the proper syntax) solved the problem. Not sure why nothing came up about that breakpoint in the debugger though, so it could still be a threading issue (I've got threading problems elsewhere) so I'm hesitant to post that as my answer until I get more info. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you have a chance to reproduce it, please file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com and include the samples of your application and a sample of Xcode while this is happening, along with the details of what your breakpoint condition was.  It's hard to say what might have been happening without those details, but it would be nice to capture the information while it is still available in case there might be something that could be done in lldb/Xcode to avoid this behavior.